# Migrating Database SQL Server to Sybase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sybase

I'm migrating a database from MS-SQL to SyBase 15.2, please propose any tools which can assist me on this task.

also please post your experience with SyBase, especially the Replicator.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the complexity of your database.

I migrated the other way, from Sybase 11/12 to MS-SQL 2000 using DTS.  I had to do some cleanup of both the schema and data.

From memory I had to use bcp to recopy some data across.  I believe the main culprits were "money" datatypes, where the values did not come across correctly.

You can also use the SQL Server Import and Export utility.  I don't know how well (if at all) that will copy indexes, constraints and the rest.  Probably just copy table definitions and data.

So DTS and bcp, which are part of SQL Server (well for SQL 2000 they were anyway), will *probably* do the job.

There are 3rd party tools such as Erwin and DbArtisan, which I haven't used for 6-8 years, but I think they'll do the job.  Not free.

Possibly you could use replication to publish a snapshot and have Sybase subscribe to it.